# How to store input in two different arrays in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to store 10 values in two arrays. 5 in each array. How do I store values that are inputted by the user into the arrays?

One array is for strings (names of products) and the other is for the prices of the products in the first array. I've tried to append the input with no success.

```
products = []
prices = []

print ("Enter the names of the five products.")
for i in range(5):
    products.append(input())

print ("Enter the prices of the five products.")
for i in range(5):
    prices.append(input())

print (products, end  = "")
print (prices, end  = "")

print ("Press enter to quit ")
quit = input()
```

Expected results: for the first array to store five names of inputted products and the second array to have five prices.

Actual results: the program won't start. It crashes almost immediately.

Edit:

I'm looking for the code to create output like this:

```
['Apple', 'Micorsoft', 'Sony', 'Oppo', 'Samsung']
['100', '80', '70', '60', '40']
```

I hope that makes the question easier to understand.

Comment: Where is `input` defined?

Comment: you need a `loop`

Comment: I think you first need to understand how to use `input`. The rest will work as you expect it.

Comment: Paste your whole program. What does "the program won't start" mean? Does it throw an exception? It crashes?

Answer (score 1):

Your current program will execute and end up with the following:

```
Enter the names of the five products.
Enter the prices of the five products.
[<built-in function input>]
[<built-in function input>]
```

What you need is a loop that will take the input from the user using the `input()` function:

```
products = []
prices = []

print ("Enter the names of the five products.")
for i in range(5):
    products.append(input())

print ("Enter the prices of the five products.")
for i in range(5):
    prices.append(input())

print(products)
print(prices)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter the names of the five products.
Apple
Micorsoft
Sony
Oppo
Samsung
Enter the prices of the five products.
100
80
70
60
40
['Apple', 'Micorsoft', 'Sony', 'Oppo', 'Samsung']
['100', '80', '70', '60', '40']
```

EDIT:

To avoid carriage return `\r`:

```
print(products, end  = "")
```

Comment: Getting close to what I want, but the output includes "/r" for some reason. Do you know why?

Comment: @JoshuaLankamp The `'\r'` character is the carriage return, and the carriage return-newline pair is both needed for newline, I've edited my answer.

Comment: The Output I got was: 

['a\r',b\r,c\r,d\r,e\r] 

['10\r,12\r,14\r,17\r,18\r]

Comment: This looks useful. I'll give it another try.

Comment: Tried it again. The output I'm now getting is:

['a\r', 'b\r', 'c\r', 'd\r', 'e\r']['10\r', '12\r', '14\r', '17\r', '18\r']Press enter to quit.

I should mention that I've added "print ("Press enter to quit ")
quit = input()" After print(prices). I've edited my code above to what it is currently.

Comment: @JoshuaLankamp please do not edit your original code posted in the question, you may add the edit part afterwards as it makes the new users hard to understand the original problem. PS. the output you're presenting doesn't seem accurate. Are you using Python 3.x? This code is tested and posted.

Comment: The output I received is like yours above, with other values typed in obviously. I'm not sure what version of python I'm using, since I'm using a college classroom pc, but I think it is the latest version. You said the code was posted but I don't see it.

Comment: @JoshuaLankamp What other values? you may check the version by `python -V` in command line. PS. My code in the answer gives the exact output.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your program to something like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

products = []
prices = []

print ("Enter the names of the five products.")
for i in range(1,6):
    products.append(raw_input(str(i) + " :"))

print ("Enter the prices of the five products.")
for i in range(1,6):
    prices.append(raw_input(str(i) + " :"))

print (products)
print (prices)
```

Comment: I gave it a try, but the code you suggested still crashes like my original code did. I did see it print text to the screen briefly however.

Comment: Can you append `raw_input()` to the end of the program and try ?

Comment: After the second for loop?

Comment: after `print (prices)`

Comment: I've changed the code in the question above, so you might want to have another look.